# React / Redux - Dispatching several action too fast

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm currently working on a simple use case : fetching data, and showing it.
For this, i made 3 actions : loading, failure, success that i dispatch according my functions.

The problem is that, sometimes, the success is triggered just after the loading... And i just receive one call in mapStateToProps instead of two.

My code is like this to update UI while fetching data :

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    if (prevProps.isLoading && !this.props.isLoading) {
      if (this.props.error) {
        this.enqueueSnackbar(this.props.error, "error");
        return;
      }

      this.enqueueSnackbar("Success!", "success");
      this.props.history.push(routes.ITEMS);
    }
  }
```

isLoading is always false because i just receive the success due to the speed of the receiption...

I tried with a timeout and it's working 100% of the time, but i would like a cleaner solution...

Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you also post the code of your action where the events are dispatched and of the reducer where the state change is done

Comment: For my data-fetching actions, I use redux-saga. The saga handles the fetch (not a reducer) and when it got the data, it dispatches the correct event (success with the data, or the error), which is handled by a reducer that updates the state accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The model for React is a more *declarative* approach, whereas the code you have here in `componentDidUpdate` is a more *imperative* approach. Generally, with React, the view changes based on the state of the application, so in your render function you would have something like

```js
render() {
  if (this.props.loading) {
    return <LoadingComponent />
  }


  if (this.props.error) {
    return <ErrorSnackBar />
  }

  return <SuccessSnackBar />
}
```

This declarative approach will make your application easier to reason about and maintain in the long term.

If you DO find yourself needing to use imperative code for something like you have, then you will want to tie it to exactly the pieces of the state that the changes depend on. In your case, you want to show an error snackbar when there is an error, and a success snackbar when there is success. Your current code unnecessarily ties the loading state to these separate pieces of the view. You would want to use something like

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (!prevProps.error && this.props.error) {
    // An error has occurred! Notice how *any* time an error occurs this
    // will run, not just when loading state changes
    this.enqueueSnackBar(this.props.error, 'error')
  }

  if (!prevProps.fetchedData && this.props.fetchedData) {
    // The data has been fetched! Do your stuff here.
    this.enqueueSnackBar("Success!", "success")
}
```